# Set background color for unselected ListViewItem for windows 8.1 app

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

I am trying to style a windows 8.1 ListView to show a background colour for unselected items in a listview.
This is my style in app.xaml file as a resource:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <!-- Other style here -->
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter CheckHintBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckHintThemeBrush}" 
                                               CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}" 
                                               ContentMargin="4" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" 
                                               CheckSelectingBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckSelectingThemeBrush}" 
                                               DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}" 
                                               DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" 
                                               DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
                                               DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" 
                                               FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderThemeBrush}" 
                                               HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                               Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" PointerOverBackgroundMargin="1" 
                                               PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
                                               PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
                                               ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" 
                                               SelectedPointerOverBorderBrush="#FF2a63a8" 
                                               SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True" 
                                               SelectedForeground="White" 
                                               SelectedPointerOverBackground="#FF4979b3" 
                                               SelectedBorderThickness="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCompactSelectedBorderThemeThickness}" 
                                               SelectedBackground="#FF2a5fa3" 
                                               VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                    </ListViewItemPresenter>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

With reference to attached image, when I set the background color here:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
```

I get the corresponding output as "LightGray background" (column 2)
When I set it to transparent, I get it as "Transparent Background" (column 1)

BUT I want it as what's shown in 3rd column "What the UI should be like"

I have tried everything. Even set the background colour via Model property, but it still looks like as shown in 2nd column.

Any help appreciated.

[image: Existing styles output]